# Explicit form of the frobenuis norm of difference between the full matrix and its best rank approximation.

Tags: mathematical-statistics, spatial, covariance-matrix, gaussian-process

Suppose I have a Gaussian process regression $Y(s)= x(s)\beta +w(s) + \epsilon (s) $ where $w(s)$ is the spatial process and $\epsilon(s)$ is the nugget effect. I have a bit of difficulties understanding how to achieve the explicit form of $$ ||\text{Cov}(y(s,s')) - \text{Cov}(w(s, s'))||^{2}_{F}$$ given that:

1. cov$(w(s, s')) = \psi^{T}(s)\Lambda\psi(s') = \sum_{i=1}^{m} \psi_{i}(s)\lambda_{i}\psi^{T}_{i}(s')$ (You can consider this as the best m -rank approximation of $\text{Cov}(y(s))$).
2. cov$(y(s, s')) = c(s, s')$ (You can consider this as the full matrix 
   $u \times v$) and $ m < u, v$.

where $\psi(s) = (\psi_{1}(s)..., \psi_{m}(s))^T$ are the eigenfunction and $\Lambda $ is the $m$ x $m$ diagonal matrix with eigenvalues.

This was what I did.
\begin{align*}
||\text{Cov}(y(s,s')) - \text{Cov}(w(s, s'))||^{2}_{F}
&= \sum_{i=1}^{u}\sum_{j=1}^{v} \left (c(s_{i}, s_{j}) - \psi^{T}(s_{i})\Lambda\psi(s_{j}) \right )^2 \\ 
&= \sum_{i=1}^{u}\sum_{j=1}^{v} \left (c^{2}(s_{i}, s_{j}) - 2c(s_{i}, s_{j})\sum_{k=1}^{m}\psi_{k}^{T}(s_{i})\Lambda_{k}\psi_{k}(s_{j}) + \left(\sum_{k=1}^{m}\psi_{k}^{T}(s_{i})\Lambda_{k}\psi_{k}(s_{j})\right)^2 \right )\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{u}\sum_{j=1}^{v} c^{2}(s_{i}, s_{j}) - 2\sum_{i=1}^{u}\sum_{j=1}^{v}c(s_{i}, s_{j})\sum_{k=1}^{m}\psi_{k}^{T}(s_{i})\Lambda_{k}\psi_{k}(s_{j}) + \sum_{i=1}^{u}\sum_{j=1}^{v}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m}\psi_{k}^{T}(s_{i})\Lambda_{k}\psi_{k}(s_{j}) \right )^2
\end{align*}

This is where I got to. I really don't know how to proceed from the use of the summations and the kind of assumptions to make in order to achieve the desired results.